# Openstack can admin impersonate as another user to create a VM

Tags: openstack, keystone

I need to implement VM creation workflow such that admin creates VM for a user after verifying his request.

Currently, if admin creates the VM, it is marked as owner of this instance.

- Can we either change or add another owner to the instance?
- Can admin impersonate as another user to create a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An admin cannot impersonate another user.  However, in practice this is not the problem you might think, because access to resources in OpenStack is controlled by *projects* (basically, groups) rather than by individual users.

You can add the `admin` user to other tenants, and then set `OS_PROJECT_NAME` (and/or `OS_PROJECT_ID`) in your environment to the appropriate project when creating resources (such as servers, networks, etc).

When you create a resource as a particular project, any member of that project will have access to that resource.

Note that in earlier versions of OpenStack, projects were referred to as *tenants* and the correponding variables where `OS_TENANT_NAME` and `OS_TENANT_ID`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This does look like a neat solution, provided I can create separate project for each user.
What if all users belong to common project(say demo). Can admin ensure that another user can also access an instance created by admin?

Comment: All users that are members of the same project have *openstack* access to all resources owned by the project -- they can delete them, update them, etc.  SSH access to a nova server depends on which key was specified when booting it.